# How can we implement loop constructs in genetic programming?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

I've been playing around with genetic programming for some time and started wondering how to implement looping constructs.

In the case of for loops I can think of 3 parameters:

- **start**: starting value of counter
- **end**: counter upper limit
- **expression**:  the expression to execute while counter < end

Now the tricky part is the *expression* because it generates the same value in every iteration unless *counter* is somehow injected into it. So I could allow the symbol for *counter* to be present in the expressions but then how do I prevent it from appearing outside of for loops?

Another problem is using the result of the expression. I could have a for loop which sums the results, another one that multiplies them together but that's limiting and doesn't seem right. I would like a general solution, not one for every operator.

So does anyone know a good method to implement loops in genetic programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's tricky. Genetic programming (the original Koza-style GP) is best suited for functional-style programming, i.e. there is no internal execution state and every node is a function that returns (and maybe takes) values, like lisp. That is a problem when the node is some loop - it is not clear what the node should return.

You could also design your loop node as a binary node. One parameter is a boolean expression that will be called before every loop and if true is returned, the loop will be executed. The second parameter would be the loop expression.

The problem you already mentioned, that there is no way of changing the loop expression. You can solve this by introducing a concept of some internal state or variables. But that leaves you with another problems like the need to define the number of variables. A variable can be realized e.g. by a tuple of functions - a setter (one argument, no return value, or it can return the argument) and getter (no arguments, returns the value of the variable).

Regarding the way of handling the loop result processing, you could step from GP to strongly typed GP or STGP for short. It is essentialy a GP with types. Your loop could then be effectively a function that returns a list of values (e.g. numbers) and you could have other functions that take such lists and calculate other values...

There is another GP algorithm (my favourite), called Grammatical Evolution (or GE) which uses context-free grammar to generate the programs. It can be used to encode type information like in STGP. You could also define the grammar in a way that classical c-like for and while loops can be generated. Some extensions to it, like Dynamically Defined Functions, could be used to implement variables dynamically.

If there is anything unclear, just comment on the answer and I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: I will experiment with the internal state method, although as you said, it is not very functional-style. Will also investigate STGP, haven't heard about it yet. Maybe I'll also look into GE (I have a rough understanding of it) but at the moment I'm mainly interested in Gene Expression Programming. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you aren't committed to traditional Koza-style GP, you can also play around with other kinds of evolved code that are even farther afield, such as PushGP (http://faculty.hampshire.edu/lspector/push.html) or Avida (https://github.com/devosoft/avida), both of which allow for looping.

Comment: I've personally implemented [stack based genetic programs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d992/1698680ca2327d7c242ebdb530707f170a4e.pdf), your pretty much just implementing a very basic virtual machine at that point, and it doesn't have the limitations of kozas style GP trees, which also lends itself to GPU processing very well.  You can loop via push/popping instructions, or actual jump instructions if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with zegkjan's answer is that there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Theres actually a simpler, and at times, better solution to creating GP datastructures than koza trees, instead using stacks.

This method is called [Stack Based Genetic Programming](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d992/1698680ca2327d7c242ebdb530707f170a4e.pdf), which is quite old (1993).  This method of genetic programming removes trees entirely, you have a instruction list, and a data stack (where your functional and terminal set remain the same).   You iterate through your instruction list, pushing values to the data stack, and pulling values to consume them, and returning a new value/values to the stack given your instruction.  For example, consider the following genetic program.

```
0: PUSH TERMINAL X
1: PUSH TERMINAL X
2: MULTIPLY (A,B)
```

Iterating through this program will give you:

```
step1: DATASTACK X
step2: DATASTACK X, X
step3: DATASTACK X^2
```

Once you have executed all program list statements, you then just take off the number of elements from the stack that you care about (you can get multiple values out of the GP program this way).   This ends up being a fast and extremely flexible method (memory locality, number of parameters doesn't matter, nor number of elements returned) you can implement fairly quickly.

To loop in this method, you can create a separate stack, an execution stack, where new special operators are used to push and pop multiple statements from the execution stack at once to be executed afterwards.

Additionally you can simply include a jump statement to move backwards in your program list, make a loop statement, or have a separate stack holding loop information.  With this a genetic program could theoretically develop its own for loop.

```
0: PUSH TERMINAL X
1: START_LOOP 2
2: PUSH TERMINAL X
3: MULTIPLY (A, B)
4: DECREMENT_LOOP_NOT_ZERO

step1: DATASTACK X
       LOOPSTACK 
step2: DATASTACK X
       LOOPSTACK [1,2]
step3: DATASTACK X, X
       LOOPSTACK [1,2]
step4: DATASTACK X^2
       LOOPSTACK [1,2]
step5: DATASTACK X^2
       LOOPSTACK [1,1]
step6: DATASTACK X^2, X
       LOOPSTACK [1,1]
step7: DATASTACK X^3
       LOOPSTACK [1,1]
step8: DATASTACK X^3
       LOOPSTACK [1,0]
```

Note however, with any method, it may be difficult for a GP program to actually evolve a member that has a loop, and even if it does, its likely that such a mechanism would result in a poor fitness evaluation at the start, likely removing it from the population any way.   To fix this type of problem (potentially good innovations dying early due to poor early fitness), you'll need to include the concepts of [demes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deme_(biology)) in your genetic program to isolate genetically disparate populations.

Comment: The downside is, however, that it is often very hard to decode how the program actually works. With trees, it is just... trees. With stacks, the complexity (of what the program does, not necessarily its size) skyrockets very easily. If you don't need to know how the program works, it's fine, but if you do, it may be a problem.

Comment: @zegkljan That could be true, but I find when using genetic programming to evolve programs stack based methods tend to be the better option where Koza trees are more useful for physical phenomena and node topologies like circuits and neural networks (indeed Koza initially used Koza trees to create circuits).

Comment: Yes, of course, different algorithms are useful for different problems :). Sounds like no-free-lunch to me. I myself am doing a lot of symbolic regression where we need mathematical formulas so I'm much more familiar with (and maybe biased towards) trees.